# Training loss and validation loss in convolutional auto encoder is not decreasing much

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

Why the training loss and validation loss in convolutional auto encoder is not decreasing. The training data is of dimension `10496x1024` and `CAE` is trained with `32x32` size image patches in `keras`. I have already tried `l2regularization` but did not help much. I am trainig for 20 epochs. What could be the other alternatives ?

The output :

> Epoch 1/20 10496/10496 [========] - 52s - loss: 0.4029 - val_loss:
>   0.3821
>
> Epoch 2/20 10496/10496 [========] - 52s - loss: 0.3825 - val_loss:
>   0.3784
>
> Epoch 3/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 52s - loss: 0.3802 - val_loss:
>   0.3772
>
> Epoch 4/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 51s - loss: 0.3789 - val_loss:
>   0.3757
>
> Epoch 5/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 52s - loss: 0.3778 - val_loss:
>   0.3752
>
> Epoch 6/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 51s - loss: 0.3770 - val_loss:
>   0.3743
>
> Epoch 7/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 54s - loss: 0.3763 - val_loss:
>   0.3744
>
> Epoch 8/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 51s - loss: 0.3758 - val_loss:
>   0.3735
>
> Epoch 9/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 51s - loss: 0.3754 - val_loss:
>   0.3731
>
> Epoch 10/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 51s - loss: 0.3748 - val_loss:
>   0.3739
>
> Epoch 11/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 51s - loss: 0.3745 - val_loss:
>   0.3729
>
> Epoch 12/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 54s - loss: 0.3741 - val_loss:
>   0.3723
>
> Epoch 13/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 51s - loss: 0.3736 - val_loss:
>   0.3718
>
> Epoch 14/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 52s - loss: 0.3733 - val_loss:
>   0.3716
>
> Epoch 15/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 52s - loss: 0.3731 - val_loss:
>   0.3717
>
> Epoch 16/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 51s - loss: 0.3728 - val_loss:
>   0.3712
>
> Epoch 17/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 49s - loss: 0.3725 - val_loss:
>   0.3709
>
> Epoch 18/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 36s - loss: 0.3723 - val_loss:
>   0.3710
>
> Epoch 19/20 10496/10496 [=======] - 37s - loss: 0.3721 - val_loss:
>   0.3708
>
> Epoch 20/20 10496/10496 ========] - 37s - loss: 0.3720 - val_loss:
>   0.3704

Comment: Without your network architecture, it is impossible to answer your question. Looks like your model isn't complex enough to handle your data, so both errors are large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your network is still learning, and is not slowing down so much at epoch 20. You can try a higher learning rate, and more epochs with an early stopping method if you have enough data.
This approach can be applied also with regularization methods and k-fold cross validation.